# How do I compile from C++ to Java with NestedVM?

Tags: cross-compiling

I finally figured out how to build [NestedVM](https://github.com/bgould/nestedvm). It's a C++ to Java compiler. You pretty much have to use CentOS to build it. The only thing now is I don't know how to use it from there. There isn't much documentation. It just says the tools will be available in upstream/install, which they were, but how am I supposed to know what to do next? Which tool do I run and how do I run the commands? Somehow I'm supposed to compile it to MIPS and then to Java bytecode. Does anyone have any more experience with this? I tried researching, but it didn't really help.

Comment: This is not a question about C++ (the language) really. More about running java binaries. Doesn't it get compiled to a .jar file? (which is about the only thing I know from java)

Comment: Yeah it does, but it isn't clear how to start that process

Comment: Just a guess, google came up with this : https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-run-jar-file-on-linux

Comment: I have gotten a little further. It turns out the makefile in the main directory has some sort of script you can use, but then you can also use one of the binary compilers `mips-unknown-elf-gcc` and then run `java -jar compiler.jar -outfile myclass.class -o supportCall com.test.myclass {mips file}`, but my java class didn't turn out good at all, so I'm still figuring this out. I don't know how to use the makefile either